# How do I get the NCR Rangers to stop hunting me down?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I killed ranger [Ranger Andy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger_Andy) because I accidentally stole from him when I was trying to bring the dialogue options in order to ask him about Boone's wife. He chased me out of Novac and kept shooting at me. I got annoyed and finally just shot him.

Now, everywhere I go, NCR rangers spawn near me and try to kill my companion (Boone) and I... **How do I redeem myself with the rangers?** Or how do I at least get them to stop spawning everywhere I go?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you can try is to wear NCR armor so it appears like you are a part of them.  Keep in mind that the Legion will shoot you on sight while doing so.  Its not a huge issue as Boone tends to attack the legion anyway.  Once the NCR stop attacking you since you are disguised, you can try doing some missions for the NCR to regain your relations.

Finally, if you haven't advanced enough in the main quest yet (i.e. enter the Lucky 38), there will be a chance to reset your NCR relations at that point.

Comment: It's worth noting that the rangers are not fooled by the disguise, neither the dogs.

Comment: High ranking officers and Veteran NCR will not be tricked by the disguise.